# Trying to input variable into a function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to create a VBA code that inputs the sum function into the cell:

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LX = LR - 2
Range("B" & LX).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-LX]C:R[-4]C)"
```

But when I input `LX` into the sum function, it doesn't recognize it as a variable. How can I fix this? Because LX depends on the initial number of rows which can vary.

I don't know how to fix this. I get the run-time error '1004'.

Comment: Strings have to be concatenated by `&` (not a plus (+)) --> `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & LX & "]C:R[-4]C)"`. Additional tip: Read [How to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23913882/16578424) and [How to avoid copy/paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64611707/16578424).

Comment: Let's say your data is in `A1:B20` i.e. `LR = 20`. Where do you want to put the formula and what should it sum up e.g. `B22` and `B2:B20`?

Answer (score 2):

As states in the comments above, you need to take `LX` out of the parenthesis of the formula.

Also, you should try to avoide using `Select` and `ActiveCell`, and instead use fully qualified refence objects:

*Modified code:*

```
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sht
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LX = LR - 2
    .Range("B" & LX).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-" & LX & "]C:R[-4]C)"
End With
```